# Boxed text not in a contract according to the Chicago manual of style

Tags: chicago-manual-of-style

I heard that any text in a box is not part of a contract according to Chicago manual of style, but I couldn't find this exact rule in the manual. Could you show me where this rule is in the manual?

https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/dam/jcr:bba47b07-61ba-41c3-8c79-33c005c1f56d/CMSfacsimile_all.pdf

Comment: The Chicago manual of style doesn't mention "contracts"  at all.  The closest it comes is "contractions." Where did you "hear" this?

Comment: What constitutes part of a contract is down to law, not some self-appointed style police.  Ignore what you heard.

Comment: I wonder if the Chicago style guide (or some other style guide) differentiates between rules (which are in the main text and not in boxes), and text in boxes which provides examples or explanation. Then maybe the OP has mis-read, mis-heard, or mis-remembered something about the Chicago manual of style, and is confusing a contract with the Chicago manual of style.

Comment: @StuartF In this sense, does the Chicago style guide mentions the difference beween rules and examples/explanation using boxes?